# How to compute the limite of $\ln(n)x_n$ as $n$ goes to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x_1\in ]0,1[$ and for $n\ge 1$, $(n+1)x_{n+2}-nx_{n+1}=\ln(1+x_{n+1})$. 
Compute $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(n)x_n$$

Comment: Try letting $x_n = c/\log(n)$ where $c$ is a constant.  Substitute into the recurrence relation, solve for $c$.  Because $c/\log(n) << 1$, you can Taylor-expand the log function on the right.

Comment: @Techer01 there is obviously a typo in your statement. You define $x_1$, and then your recurrence relation is written for $n \geq 2$... Are you sure the recurrence relation is good ?

Comment: @D.B. This does not seem to work... Could you precise your idea ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, my comment was really just a quick suggestion to get started.  I did not actually try it out myself.  I guessed that a Taylor expansion to get rid of the log in the recursive definition might help, but maybe it doesn't.

Comment: If $x_1 = 0$, then it looks like $x_n = 0$ for all $n$.  In this case, the limit in question is zero.

Comment: Yes, but you are not allowed to suppose that $x_n = c/\log(n)$ ! It is like you are starting from what you have to prove... Moreover, $x_1$ cannot be $0$. That's good to give hints, but try to check that your ideas are good ;)